# PowerBI - Why am I unable to create bins for this calculated column?

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, histogram

I currently have the following formula behind a calculated column:

```
Relative Error = 
VAR ActualValue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table1[Value]),
        FILTER(Table1, Table1[Date] = EARLIER(Table1[Date]) && Table1[Series Type] = "Actuals" && Table1[Country] = EARLIER(Table1[Country]))
    )
VAR ForecastedValue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table1[Value])
    )
Return    
    IF('Table1'[Series Type] = "Current Forecast" || 'Table1'[Series Type] = "Actuals" || ActualValue = 0, 0, (ForecastedValue-ActualValue/ActualValue ))
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message when I attempt to bin all of these values (i.e. I click on new group for this column):

A circular dependency was detected: Table1[Relative Error], Table1[Relative Error (bin)], Table1[Relative Error]

I do not understand where the circularity comes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to duplicate fields, also using CALCULATE(...,ALLEXCEPT(..)) syntax but it does not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Data groups is the equivalent of a Calculated Column in the backend (see link below on detailed explainion on circular references with multiple Calculated Columns).

This part is causing the issue:

```
VAR ForecastedValue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table1[Value])
    )
```

Being a calculated column, the above is equivalent to:

```
VAR ForecastedValue =  Table1[Value]
```

So try dropping the `CALCULATE` here and then it should be fine.

- This is a great worth while read: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-circular-dependencies/
- Avoid `x/ y`, instead use `DIVIDE(x, y)` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-divide-function-operator